# Using 'execlp' System Call to run current program recursively

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, exec, command-line-arguments, system-calls

I am trying to use execlp to call my program inside of my program (for a project) and am having trouble. I have created a sample project which should count down from  `n` to 0 (essentially run n times). Each time I run it, I get the first decrement and then I get a seg fault. Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

P.S Fairly new to System calls in C, so explain thoroughly if possible. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int n = atoi(argv[1]);

    char newParameters[2];
    sprintf(newParameters, "%d", n - 1);

    if (n != 0)
    {
        execlp("./tmp", newParameters, (char *)NULL);
    }

    printf("The program has finished.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The C program is called tmp.

Comment: What is the test command line? `newParameters` can only hold a one character string. So any input number greater than 9 will result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: Should be `execlp("./tmp", "./tmp", newParameters, (char *)NULL);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [execlp manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp):

> The initial argument for these functions is the name of a file that is to be executed.
>
> The const char *arg and subsequent ellipses in the execl(), execlp(), and execle() functions can be thought of as arg0, arg1, ..., argn. Together they describe a list of one or more pointers to null-terminated strings that represent the argument list available to the executed program. The first argument, by convention, should point to the filename associated with the file being executed.

That is, the first argument to `execlp` is the executable file to run. The second parameter corresponds to `argv[0]` passed to `main`. The third parameter is `argv[1]` and so on. So the `execlp` in this case needs to be:

```
execlp("./tmp", "./tmp", newParameters, NULL);
```

Or better still use `argv[0]` rather than a hard coded executable name so that it can work no matter how the program is linked:

```
execlp(argv[0], argv[0], newParameters, NULL);
```

Other things to note:

- `newParameters` can only hold a single character string (including NUL terminator). So any command line with a number greater than 9 will result in undefined behaviour.
- Other good practices: Always check `argc` before using `argv` values and always check the return value of all function calls, specifically `execlp` in this case.

Comment: This worked great. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`execlp(2)` cannot be used to run a program recursively, because no new process is created.  The current context (process address space, data, etc.) is loaded (overwritten) with the new mapping to execute the same program again, and the data segment, the stack and memory segments are detached and trashed to create the new ones.  When this instance finally `exit(2)`s, there's no process backed up to return to.  To create a new process you need to use `fork(2)`, not `execlp(2)`.